# Как в js получить ссылки на обьекты, сохранить их в массив и дальше с ними работать

Tags: javascript, jquery

На моей странице есть более 20 блоков такой разметки:

```
 <div class="CountryBlock CountryBlock_theme_country">
      <a href="/" class="tdn">
        <div class="CountryBlock-Header">
          <div class="HeaderFlag" style="background-image: url('/img/<?php echo $countrty['flag'];?>');"></div>
          <span class="HeaderName"><?php echo $country['name'];?></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

В каждом блоке есть элемент **HeaderName**, который содержит текст. На странице есть инпут, который реагирует на введенный текст пользователя и вызывает функцию.

**Вопрос:**

Можно ли каким то образом, в js функции сохранить ссылки на обьекты, в которых текст содержит подстроку, которую вводит пользователь в инпуте?

Вот примерно то, как я думал двигаться, но это не верно. Помогите решить мой вопрос.

```
function CountryFilter()
{
    var keyword = $("#CountryFilter").val();

    var items = $(".CountryBlock").find(".HeaderName").text().includes(keyword);
    items.each(function(i){
        //к примеру каждому блоку установить черный фон через .css()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function CountryFilter()
{
    var keyword = $("#CountryFilter").val();
    
    /*var items = $(".CountryBlock").find(".HeaderName").text().includes(keyword);
    ^ было не верно, ибо в переменной items, после вызова метода .text(), сохранялась строка с текстовыми значениями спанов, а после вызова .includes(keyword) и вовсе булево*/
    var items = $(".CountryBlock");
    items.each(function(i,item){
      item=$(item).removeClass('becomeBlack')
      if(item.find(".HeaderName").text().includes(keyword)) item.addClass('becomeBlack')
    });
}
$('button').click(CountryFilter)
```

```css
.CountryBlock{
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.becomeBlack{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CountryBlock CountryBlock_theme_country">
      <a href="/" class="tdn">
        <div class="CountryBlock-Header">
          <div class="HeaderFlag" style="background-image: url('/img/<?php echo $countrty['flag'];?>');"></div>
          <span class="HeaderName">SOME TEXT HERE</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
 <div class="CountryBlock CountryBlock_theme_country">
      <a href="/" class="tdn">
        <div class="CountryBlock-Header">
          <div class="HeaderFlag" style="background-image: url('/img/<?php echo $countrty['flag'];?>');"></div>
          <span class="HeaderName">AND HERE IS ANOTHER TEXT</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
<input id="CountryFilter" value="ANOTHER">
<button>Filter It</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нужно сделать вот так

```
const items = $(".CountryBlock")
    .find(".HeaderName")
    .filter((index,el) => el.innerHTML.includes(keyword) );
```

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.innerHTML.includes')

Comment: Подскажите как дальше должен выглядеть цикл для применения css({"background":"#000"}); для этих элементов.

Comment: Вообщем ваш вариант пока не работает. Где то ошибка